# Validate UK phone number including its area code

Tags: php, regex

I have written regex (combining available from diff threads) to validate the UK numbers.

As per regex it should validate the number `0208 123-4567`. But it does not. What is the issue?

[Example : http://ideone.com/pm1GT2](http://ideone.com/pm1GT2)

```
<?php
$number = '0208 123-4567';
validateUsNumber($number);
function validateUsNumber($number)
{
    $number= preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $number);
    $pattern = '/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)|\(?02\d{3}\)|\(?01\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/';
    $match = preg_match($pattern,$number);  
    if ($match != false)
    {
    echo " We have a valid UK phone number";
    }
    else
    {
    echo " We have an invalid UK phone number " ;
    }
}
```

Comment: An interesting question, and a potential usability nightmare; if you are planning to add this to a website, my advice is not to. In most cases where a website stops a form from validating based on a telephone number test, there is an edge case (with a valid but disallowed number) that causes a user to abandon the process/site in frustration. And, in many cases, it should be OK not to provide a telephone number at all.

Comment: @halfer: I get user data and need to validate the number. So I need it. Due you have anything to say how can I make it work best?

Comment: You need it because you need it? Heh, a recursive justification `;)`

Comment: @halfer In my experience, some clients hate clearly fake phone numbers like `000000000` in their databases. They prefer to have fake records fed with random valid numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uk+phone+number

Comment: @Álvaro, yes - at least all the zeroes can be weeded out when they send them to the auto-dialler computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this regexp instead:

```
$pattern = '^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^';
```

So your code should look like this:

```
<?php
$number = '0208 123-4567';
$number = '+44 20 8985 5577'; // or this
validateUsNumber($number);
function validateUsNumber($number)
{
    $pattern = '^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^';
    $match = preg_match($pattern,$number);  
    if ($match != false)
    {
    echo " We have a valid UK phone number";
    }
    else
    {
    echo " We have an invalid UK phone number " ;
    }
}
```

This is taken from http://www.aa-asterisk.org.uk/index.php/Regular_Expressions_for_Validating_and_Formatting_GB_Telephone_Numbers and you can find more GB-specific telephone number validations there. I used "1.1 Match GB telephone number in any format".

Answer (score 2):

it will match this :

```
02083) 123456
```

and not this :

```
0208 123-4567
```

because of a few reasons

- you have the second bracket compulsary, change `\(?02\d{3}\)` to `\(?02\d{3}\)?`
- you have kept {3} and trying to match with 2 digits, change `\(?02\d{3}\)?` to `\(?02\d{2}\)?`
- you have not included - hiphen anywhere, so obviously it wont match. change the last part to `\s?\d{3}-\s?\d{3}$`.
- your example has 4 digits after hiphen ( -4567 ), so change the last part of your regex for quantifier `{4}`.

Thus your final regex should look like  :

```
^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)|\(?02\d{3}\)?|\(?01\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$
```

this regex will match your need
`0208 123-4567`

as a suggestion, remove the `+` from the regex check
demo here : http://regex101.com/r/kM8bC7

Comment: `\s?\d{3}-\s?\d{4}` won't work if there is a space instead of a hyphen (you made the hyphen compulsory), I think you mean `\s?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}`

Comment: @acarlon yea this will be better and less prone to errors :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is basically looking for a nicely formatted number, but its being tested against the result of stripping non-numeric characters. You'll never have leading `+44`, white space or parenthesis after this:

```
$number= preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $number);
```

Comment: Your validator did not match data so you changed data? Honestly, I'm not sure of what you have in mind.