# Combining regex to validate UK and US phone number

Tags: php, regex

I have two regex. One to validate UK number (from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195191/validate-uk-phone-number-including-its-area-code)) and another to validate US number:

1. `^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^`
2. `/\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}/`

I want to combine both of this so that I can validate any US or UK number.

Does or `|` operation suffice for this?

Here I combined both of them using | but it does not validate the number:

http://regex101.com/r/wD4dI9

Comment: The OP has concisely stated their problem __and__ shown their attempt as well as why it didn't work. I do not believe this question deserves downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your `|` operator should be fine for that. It would look like this:

```
/((^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$)|(\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}))/
```

It works for the regex demo in your question: http://regex101.com/r/zX2cE5

Comment: @user123, I have updated the regex, it doesn't contain any errors now.

Comment: I was trying this (800) 733-6644

Comment: @user123, I have included regex for your specific case. it works now. please check it out.

Comment: thanks, I will correct this answer. Why downvote here can you please tell me dude? or help me to compenset

Comment: and can you please tell me what changes you have made here?

Comment: @user123, I did not downvote. Your question seems fine to me. It shows your attempt as well (+1 from me). I simply took your two regexes (rg1 and rg2 for example) and did `((rg1)|(rg2))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51098/discussion-between-sshashank124-and-user123)

Comment: @sshashank124: if people ask for your email/VOIP/whatever here, they are looking for a free private support channel. It is usually best to direct them back to Stack Overflow `:)`.

Comment: you seem enough sound with PHP, just for suggestion and guideline in future \

Comment: @user123, Actually I'm more of a `python` and `regex` person. :\

Comment: @sshashank124: hey dude, can you please have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391787/filtering-and-trasforming-number-using-regex